# Query about xml parsing in android

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing

I am working on an android app in which i have to fetch data from a .Net webservice Initially methods of webservice returning simple strings.That's fine my code is working fine and fetch strings smoothly.But my problem starts when methods return objects,I know object holds the data in XML form.I also confirmed it by debugging my code,the resultant object holds the data given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<soap:Body>

<UserInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

<UserInfoResult>

<UserName>Himanshu</UserName>

<Email>Himanshu@XXXXXXXX.com</Email>

</UserInfoResult>

</UserInfoResponse>

</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

and my code to consume the web service is:-

```
public void objData(){

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);
        Log.d("request", request.toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Log.d("envelope", envelope.toString());

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        Log.d("envelope", envelope.toString());

        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        aht.debug=true;
        Log.d("aht", aht.toString());

        try
        {
            aht.call(OBJ_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive results = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println("results="+results);
            tv4.setText(""+results);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tv4.setText(e.getClass().toString());
            Log.d("Error",e.getClass().toString());
        }

    }
```

The object `results` holds the xml data.Now my problem is that when i print the data of that object by using the code `tv4.setText(""+results);` it gives me `class java.lang.ClassCastException`.I know that this is not the right approach to get object's xml data,I have to parse it.But i dont know how to parse object.So please help me to parse xml contained object.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use SoapPrimitive for complex object, you have to cast the response like below

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

Then if you want to cast it to an entity object(similar to the object you are sending via .net web service) you have to do like this.

Entity class

```
public class EmLogin {

private String _id;

private String _pwd;


public EmLogin() {
}

public String getId() {
    return _id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this._id = id;
}

public String getPwd() {
    return _pwd;
}

public void setPwd(String pwd) {
    this._pwd = pwd;
}

//this is the place you are setting the SoapObject as a param
public EmLogin(SoapObject so) throws ParseException {

    this._id = so.getProperty("Id").toString();// these are the properties of your xml objs
    this._pwd = so.getProperty("PasswordHash").toString();

}}
```

the way of setting the retrived soapobject to the entity class as follows.

```
EmLogin = null;
if (yourSoapObject!= null) {
    // here you are parsing the soapobject to the emlogin object as a param
    emLogin = new EmLogin(yourSoapObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch complex data objects from soap, define object as KvmSerializale by implementing KvmSerializable, see link:

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html